# Using synonyms to express same meaning in context

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-choice

Are the following sentences applicable/natural to use ?                           ( grammatically and conversational speaking )

1. Telecommunication companies claim that the government closes VOIP services.
2. Telecommunication companies request that the government closes VOIP services.

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide any more information, it would be helpful. But with the information given, it  seems that you would like to know the sentences that are expressing the same meaning. Number 5 sounds like the best answer compared to number one and two. Number three and four do not seem to match like the others.

Comment: Thank you.But, can we say that number 3 and 4  are grammatically right ?

Comment: I am still not sure exactly what question you are trying to answer. Number 3 and 4 are technically grammatical but do not seem to fit in with the rest and do not sound as right.

Comment: what I mean whether they sound natural to your ears  (Number 2&3)  or not regardless the context.